# How to return a part of file concurrent efficient?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In our project, we combine lots file into one large file , suppose to be 4~12GB

Now i need to write a server to process client request,

Each request client would like to retrieve a part in this large file or push a new file into this large file(tail),

So what's the best way to do this in low latency?

`RandomAccessFile`? `InputStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want here is a ReentrantReadWriteLock.

This lock will allow simultaneous read operation and only one write operation at a time.
You can acquire the read lock before every read operation and release it after reading is over.
And a write lock before every write operation and release it after that.

Have your client call the mentioned code. Hope it helps.

```
final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public void checkFile(String yourData) {

    lock.readLock().lock();

    boolean toWrite = false;
    // Read the file, check for data and update toWrite accordingly
    lock.readLock().unlock();

    if (toWrite) {
        lock.writeLock().lock();

        // write the data to the file

        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best performance would be gained if you will not recombine chunks into single file. The next step is to use [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) from NIO.

Comment: no, but you may open multiple channels on single file as soon as you're not writing to the file. You may also use memory-mapped files.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Linux, I suggest to use `cat` command in bash shell to combine files. Efficient and does not require other programming language.

Example

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt >> file_combine.txt
```